# Regex for phone number allowing 9 or 10 digits

Tags: regex

I am trying to validate a regex which

- allows 10 digits
- if digit starts with 672 then it should only allow total 9 digits

I have tried below regex
`/^\d{10}$|^(672)\d{6}$/`

https://regex101.com/r/0ahnKx/1

It works for 10 digits but if number starts with 672 then also it allows 10 digits.
Could anyone help how can I fix this?
Thanks!

Comment: `/^(?!672)\d{10}$|^672\d{6}$/`

Comment: Thanks @WiktorStribiżew looks like its working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, the capturing group in your regex is redundant, it would make sense  to wrap the part of the pattern between `^` and `$` to only use single occurrences of the anchors.

To fix the issue, you need to make sure the first three digits matched by `\d{10}` are not `672`, and you can achieve that with a negative lookahead:

```php
/^((?!672)\d{10}|672\d{6})$/
/^(?:(?!672)\d{10}|672\d{6})$/
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/0ahnKx/2). *Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?:` - start of a group:

  - `(?!672)\d{10}` - no `672` substring check is triggered and then ten digits are matched
- `|` - or

  - `672\d{6}` - `672` and six digits
- `)` - end of the group
- `$`  - end of string.